# Jquery check for integer?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
    jQuery(function( $ ){

    // If no speed is set (when loading the page) set default speed

    if (!$moveSpeed) {
        var $moveSpeed = 4000;
    }

    // Move the damn autocue

 $('a.goDown').click(function(){
        alert($moveSpeed);
  $.scrollTo('#footer', $moveSpeed);
  return false;
 });

    $('a.goUp').click(function(){
        alert($moveSpeed);
  $.scrollTo('#header', $moveSpeed);
  return false;
 });


    // Speed settings for autocue

    $('a.changeSpeed').click(function(){
  $moveSpeed = $(this).attr('speed');
  return false;
 });
});

</script>
```

and if the changeSpeed is clicked, the alert box shows it is changed to the given number but it aint an integer, is there a way to convert a variable in to an integer?

thx :)

Comment: If you're going to put custom attributes on elements, strongly recommend using a `data-` prefix on them (e.g., `data-speed`). Custom attributes are invalid in HTML4 and earlier; in HTML5, they're valid if they start with `data-`. Browsers generally allow invalid attributes and so they *work*, but they make a document fail validation. [More in this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('a.changeSpeed').click(function(){
  $moveSpeed = parseInt($(this).attr('speed'),10);
  return false;
 });
```

[Javascript `parseInt` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp)

Comment: +1 Nice use of `parseInt`, but it would be even nicer if you used `this.speed` rather than the unnecessary jQuery call!

Comment: @lonesomeday - what makes you think the current `this` has a property `speed`? I assumed it was an html attribute in which case the jQuery call is legit.

Comment: @lonesomeday: Not all attributes are reflected as properties. I certainly wouldn't count on a non-standard and invalid one being reflected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's the actual problem you're having, so I'm making this answer a CW, but FYI:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

    // If no speed is set (when loading the page) set default speed

    if (!$moveSpeed) {
        var $moveSpeed = 4000;
    }
```

That `if` statement is completely non-functional, the body of it is *always* run. The `!$moveSpeed` condition will always be true. This is because `var` declares a variable within the current function, regardless of where the `var` statement actually is or whether it's inside a condition or loop. [More details in this article](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html), but basically the interpreter sees that code like this:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    var $moveSpeed;

    // If no speed is set (when loading the page) set default speed

    if (!$moveSpeed) {
        $moveSpeed = 4000;
    }
```

...and since the value of a variable that isn't initialized yet is `undefined`, and `!undefined` is `true`, you'll always set `$moveSpeed` to 4000.